# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException Error

Tags: java, string, exception, java-8, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm new to JAVA and am working on a task to:

1. Take as input a user string
2. Take as input a user integer
3. Use the integer as an increment value
4. Return all character values in the string starting from 0 ending at the last character available after incrementing.

I'm getting correct results in terminal immediately followed by the dreaded StringOutOfBoundsException error.  I'm not able to see where I am attempting to access a character in the string that is out of bounds and would be grateful for your expertise locating my error.  Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class EveryOtherCharacter
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    

    //initialize all variables to be used in this program
    String userEntry;//store user word as a String
    String error=("Invalid Entry!");//notify of error
    String purpose=("Enter a word and an increment value and we'll\nreturn each character in your word using the number you provided".)
    int increment;//store increment integer from user
    int userEntryCount;//store total count of chars in userEntry
    char value;//get character at increment value from userEntry

    System.out.println("========================START PROGRAM=============================");
   System.out.println(purpose); 

    System.out.println();//whitespace
    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
    userEntry=input.nextLine();
    userEntryCount = userEntry.length();

    System.out.print("Enter an increment value:  ");
    increment=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println();//whitespace

    value=userEntry.charAt(0);
    System.out.print(value);

    for (int count=0; count <= userEntryCount; count++)
    {
        value=userEntry.charAt(increment);
        userEntry=userEntry.substring(increment);
        System.out.print(value);
    }

    if (increment > userEntryCount && increment <= 0)
    {
        System.out.println(error);
    }
     System.out.println();//whitespace

    System.out.println("=========================END PROGRAM==============================");

   }
}
```

Here is an example of what my terminal output looks like after running this program.  Notice that the correct output is present immediately before the exception error:

```
java EveryOtherCharacter
========================START PROGRAM=============================
Enter a word and an increment value and we'll
return each character in your word using the number you provided

Enter a word: whyisthissohard
Enter an increment value:  3

wihsaException in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
at EveryOtherCharacter.main(EveryOtherCharacter.java:57)
```

Comment: `userEntry=userEntry.substring(increment);` is overriding the value of your string. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply cricket_007!  I'm not entirely certain how I can get the new value of the String "userEntry" after I have selected the user increment value.  My assumption was that it would be best to get the value and then cut the string to include everything after the increment number and then run the loop again.  I'm stuck on that.  Is there another way I can do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this using a while loop as follows:

```
while (n < length)//where n=userNumber & length=length of user word
{
    character=userEntry.charAt(n);//character becomes the character of the word at the increment value
    System.out.print(character);//print value of character at increment
    userEntry=userEntry.substring(n);//set userEntry to value of new string starting at n
    length = userEntry.length();//count the total number of characters in the new substring
}
```

After going through the logic of the for loop, I realized i had created and was trying to increment the value of i and that wasn't necessary.  You all were a really big help in making think through the problem. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

You're cutting through `whyisthissohard` by 3 each time. But you are looping through `whyisthissohard`'s length in total.

```
for (int count=0; count <= userEntryCount; count++)
{
    value=userEntry.charAt(increment);
    userEntry=userEntry.substring(increment);
    System.out.print(value);
}
```

---

```
First loop : value = 'i' ; userEntry = "isthissohard" ;
Second loop : value = 'h' ; userEntry = "hissohard";
Third loop : value = 's' ; userEntry = "sohard";
Fourth loop : value = 'a' ; userEntry = "ard";
Fifth loop => Error
```

Comment: This was a huge help!  After reading your comment, I realized that I had <= instead of "<" in the loop continuation condition.  I set a new variable to `int divisible = userEntryCount/increment;` My code looks like this now:  `for (int count=0; count < divisible; count++){...}` and my terminal output looks like  `Enter a word:  manthatwaseasy  Enter an increment value:  3  mttss` Thanks @Yassin Hajaj

Comment: So, I was wrong.  The above works but when I enter my full name, I get the same exception when the increment value is 1 or 10.  I'm really stuck on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think when the instructions say "Use the integer as an increment value", you should be using it as an actual increment value like so.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "whyisthissohard";
    int skip = 3;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += skip) { // <--- Increment value
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    }

    //Return all character values in the string
    System.out.println(sb.toString()); // wihsa

}
```

You could also print them all in the for-loop instead of adding to another string, if you want.

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007, but I haven't learned how to use the StringBuilder() yet and will have points deducted for using anything not covered in our course work to date.  Is there another way using something along the lines of what I've already coded up?

Comment: As I said in the last sentence, you can print the characters within the loop